# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination "xxx" is not a direct child of this NavGraph error in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm working on a project and while designing the screens, I think I've set up a navGraph structure that is a bit confusing and not good. What I want to do in this project is to take some values ​​of the user in splash activity, determine a start destination according to these values ​​and send this start destination to RootNavGraph in MainActivity. For example, I defined a function that I want to go to the following screens under the following conditions, in MainActivity

**MainActivity**

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
        lateinit var navHostController: NavHostController
        lateinit var startDestination:String
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            val isTokenExist: Boolean = intent.getBooleanExtra("isTokenExist", false)
            val refreshTokenResponse: NavigateState? = intent.getParcelableExtra("response")
    
            refreshTokenResponse?.let {
                startDestination = navigateIfNeeded(it,isTokenExist)
            }
    
    
            setContent {
    
                DiyetkolikTheme {
                    navHostController = rememberNavController()
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                    ) {
                        RootNavGraph(navHostController = navHostController, startDestination)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    fun navigateIfNeeded(response: NavigateState, isTokenExist:Boolean): String {

        return when {

            !isTokenExist -> RegisterScreen.SignUpStartRegisterScreen.route
            response.hasValidation == 0 -> "${RegisterScreen.SignUpVerificationPhoneCodeScreen.route}?$EMAIL={$EMAIL}&$PHONE={$PHONE}"
            response.hasValidation == 1 -> {
                when (response.eatingHabit) {
                    0 -> {
                        if (response.weight == 0 || response.goalWeight == 0) {
                            return RegisterScreen.SignUpDailyCalorieGoalScreen.route
                        } else {
                            return DietPlannerScreen.DietPlannerCalorieGoalDietPlanner.route
                        }
                    }
                    else -> RegisterScreen.SignUpPaymentScreen.route
                }
            }
            else -> DASHBOARD_ROUTE
        }
    }
}
```

**RootNavGraph**

```
@Composable
fun RootNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController
) {

    val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = viewModel()

    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = ,
        route = ROOT_ROUTE
    )
    {
        registerLoginNavGraph(navHostController, sharedViewModel)
        dashBoardNavGraph(navHostController, sharedViewModel)
       
    }
}
```

**RegisterLoginNavGraph**

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.registerLoginNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
) {


    navigation(
        startDestination = RegisterScreen.SignUpStartRegisterScreen.route,
        route = REGISTER_LOGIN_ROUTE
    ) {

        dietPlanner(navHostController, sharedViewModel)

        composable(route = RegisterScreen.SignUpStartRegisterScreen.route) {
            StartScreenRoute(navHostController)
        }
        ...
}
```

**DietPlanner**

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.dietPlanner(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
) {

    navigation(
        startDestination = DietPlannerScreen.DietPlannerCalorieGoalDietPlanner.route,
        route = DIET_PLANNER_ROUTE
    ) {

        composable(route = DietPlannerScreen.DietPlannerDataAnalysisScreen.route) {
            DataAnalysisScreenRoute(navHostController,sharedViewModel)
        }
        composable(route = DietPlannerScreen.DietPlannerCalorieGoalDietPlanner.route) {
            CalorieGoalDietPlannerRoute(navHostController,sharedViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, it goes to the screens in different navGraphs, but there is no dietPlanner in MainActivity or RootNavGraph so I get the error I shared above.

How can I get out of this complex structure or How can I solve this problem ? Do you have any idea ?

What would be a solution if it defines all navGraphs in one navGraph? I thought this way but did not implement it.  for instance

```
@Composable
fun RootNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController
) {

    val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = viewModel()

    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = ,
        route = ROOT_ROUTE
    )
    {
        registerLoginNavGraph(navHostController, sharedViewModel)
        dashBoardNavGraph(navHostController, sharedViewModel)
        dietPlanner(navHostController)
        accountScreenNavGraph(navHostController,sharedViewModel)
        bottomBarNavGraph(navHostController,sharedViewModel)
        ...
    }
}
```

What approach is this? good or bad